# Expose local server to be accessed via FileZilla publicly or remotely - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp, filezilla

I want to access my local server machine from outside of city.

I want to use FileZilla in order to upload or download files to my directory i.e:

```
/var/wwww/html/examplesite
```

What I have tried so far is that I configured `vsftpd` on my local server machine using this article:

https://www.emiprotechnologies.com/technical_notes/odoo-technical-notes-59/post/install-and-configure-vsftpd-475

Now I am successfully able to upload and download files on localhost by providing **Host: localhost**.

The main challenge here is how can I access my FTP from outside the network of localhost?

How can I remotely access this machine using FileZilla? What should I put in the **Host:**?

Comment: What is the model of your router?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Its FiberHome HG150-Ub

Comment: Do you select Advanced setup->NAT->Virtual server?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Did that already. It says: "this port 21 is used to the Broadband Router FTP server, Please choose other port"

Comment: In such case the solution may be to change the router (if applicable) with other, which do not use port 21. Or to set your software to listen to other port, 2121 for example, NAT this port and use with client this port.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Should I contact my ISP in that case?

Comment: @RomeoNinov Can I change FileZilla port to 2121?

Comment: Of course, on main screen you have: host, username, password and port

Comment: ok I will give it a try

Comment: @RomeoNinov I have added this:  2121 -> TCP/UDP. -> 192.168.10.5. Show what should be in the host field?

Comment: @RomeoNinov I tried to forward port 2121 but its not working. I am getting: Connection attempt failed with "ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server". I tired everything you suggested.